# keybindings that change mode: cannot use keybindings on the new mode

Tags: neovim, key-bindings, normal-mode, visual-mode, lua

I have defined the following keybindings:

```lua
local opts = { noremap = true }
local ll = "<leader>i"

opts["desc"] = "Send visual lines"
vim.keymap.set("v", ll .. "l", function()
  require("toggleterm").send_lines_to_terminal("visual_lines", trim_spaces, { args = vim.v.count })
end, opts)

local newopts = opts
newopts["desc"] = "Send until cursor"
newopts["noremap"] = false
vim.keymap.set("n", ll .. "c" , "maggV`a" ..ll.."l`a", newopts)
```

However, the last keybinding just select until the current line and then stop.

Looks like `<leader>il` is not called.

Should I be able to use visual mode keybindings from normal mode keybindings that switch into visual mode?

Answer (score 1):

The key code is actually `remap` and not `noremap`.

I would define it like this:

```lua
local opts = { remap = false }
local ll = "<leader>i"

opts["desc"] = "Send visual lines"
vim.keymap.set("v", ll .. "l", function()
  require("toggleterm").send_lines_to_terminal("visual_lines", trim_spaces, { args = vim.v.count })
end, opts)

local newopts = opts
newopts["desc"] = "Send until cursor"
newopts["remap"] = true
vim.keymap.set("n", ll .. "c" , "maggV`a" ..ll.."l`a", newopts)
```

Comment: I already have `newopts["noremap"] = false`, and I don't understand why you specify it two times

Comment: Sorry I didn't paid enough attention :-|

Comment: I have found the problem. It is related to the `remap` keyword that should be `remap` and not `noremap`.

Comment: you are great! thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm happy we solved your problem :-)

Comment: no, it's `noremap`, not `remap`. See [docs](https://neovim.io/doc/user/api.html#nvim_set_keymap()). With `remap` it issues an error.

Comment: @robertspierre I agree that the doc is confusing :-) But I truly believe it is `remap` and not `noremap`. An additional argument for that related to the doc is that If you do a mapping without options it will be by default `noremap` in Neovim (i.e. `remap=false`)

Comment: if you write `remap` it will throw an error when starting neovim.

Comment: I'm using Neovim 0.9.5 and I don't have the error at start. Could you tell us what is the exact error message your get and what is the version of Neovim you are using?